# Localized messages in Pentaho reports

Tags: internationalization, reporting, pentaho

I am currently trying to put a localized message in a Pentaho report. The message has one parameter which is to be inserted into the message's localized text like

*All approved disconnects of ${company} in ${region}*

How do I do that using Pentaho Report Designer? I've tried a `resource-message`. It correctly accesses a localized text defined in a resource bundle inlined with the report file but I cannot get it to substitute the placeholder for the parameter. How do I connect the message to parameters of the report?

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting the message to parameters or a field? A resource-message should be fine. You need to replace your curly braces to parentheses.

For example, in my translations file.

```
REPORT_DATE=Report Date: $(report date, date, MMMM yyyy)
```

Comment: No problem, I've still got my Pentaho Reports knowledge since we've used that extensively on my last project